# Building Docker for vuejs app

Tags: docker, vue.js

I have a problem when building docker for vuejs app

I have a vuejs app and now I want to build a docker image for it

This is my Dockerfile

```
 FROM node:7.7.2-alpine
 WORKDIR /usr/app
 COPY package.json .
 RUN npm install --quiet
 COPY . .
 EXPOSE 8080
```

And This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
   web:
      build: .
      command: npm run dev
      volumes:
         - .:/usr/app
         - /usr/app/node_modules
      ports:
         - "8080:8080"
```

When I run command docker-compose up. I get this result: [image: this result]

But when I access the url `http://localhost:8080` on my host. I get this: [image: the screen]

I don't know exactly what happened. Please help me to fix this problem.

Thank you so much.

These are my source code folders: [image: source code folders]

Comment: Can you provide access logs from the app side?

Comment: @Yuankun: Thanks. My problem is solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `npm run dev` binds to localhost only.

Add `--host 0.0.0.0` to your `webpack-dev-server` line in `package.json`:

From something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
```

To something like (`add --host 0.0.0.0`):

```
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0",
```